# Generics - Specify empty type to prevent undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-hooks, typescript-generics

In TypeScript, for the following custom React hook, is it possible to specify the initial value of `useState<F>()` (i.e. the value currently missing from the round brackets), such that it refers to an "empty" value of type `F`?

As is, the value appears to be `undefined`, and therefore the hook returns `F | undefined`. I would like it to return `F`, even if that is empty.

For example, if `F` is an array, the hook should return `[]` instead of `undefined`.

Is that possible?

```
export function useGetFromStore<T, F>(
    store: (callback: (state: T) => unknown) => unknown,
    callback: (state: T) => F
) {

    const result = store(callback) as F;
    const [state, setState] = useState<F>();

    useEffect(() => {
        setState(result);
    }, [result])

    return state;
}
```

Comment: Does this question depend on react?  If so, please tag it as such. If not, please edit the code not to refer to it, so that we can just paste an [mre] into our IDEs without needing to get react involved.

Comment: the only valid option is to pass the initial value to it. Otherwise, why would you want to make it non-undefined? It should be undefined, since initially there is no value

Answer (score 1):

Set the initial value of the `useState` to be `result`, and typescript would infer the correct type:

```
const result = store(callback) as F;
const [state, setState] = useState(result); // no need to state the type

useEffect(() => {
  setState(result);
}, [result])
```

If you don't want to use `result` as the initial value, you can pass an explicit `initialValue`, and use it instead:

```
export function useGetFromStore <T, F> (
  store: (callback: (state: T) => unknown) => unknown,
  callback: (state: T) => F,
  initialValue: F,
) {

  const result = store(callback) as F;
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(result !== undefined) setState(result);
  }, [result])

  return state;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would defeat the purpose of the hook. The hook is there to prevent an hydration error in Next.js when used in combination with Zustand for state management (Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.) Hence I cannot simply set the initial value to `result`.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I think this means there is no solution to the problem for my specific use-case.

Comment: If you don't have an initial value defined, it means that the type is `<F | undefined>`.  However, you can state explicitly an `initialValue` and use it instead (see updated answer).